# Meaning of (void (*)(void *))

Tags: c++, multithreading, casting

Can you explain me what is the meaning of `(void (*)(void *))` in the following expression:

```
(void (*)(void *))pthread_mutex_unlock
```

Comment: I tried the site, but the output isn't very clear: cast pthread_mutex_unlock into pointer to function (pointer to void) returning void

Comment: @Konstantin: In cdecl-speak, the type of a function is expressed as `function (<arguments to function>) returning <return type>`

Comment: Upvoting to balance. I see no flaw in asking such a question, c++ is a syntax pain.

Comment: @Binkan: Upvoting because you think a question is useful is one thing. Doing it because you want to deny someone else the opportunity to have their opinion heard is something else entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer brackets represent a cast. The stuff inside those brackets is the type to cast to.

In this case, it is a pointer to a function `(*)`, taking a `void*` argument, and returning `void` (i.e. nothing).

It is used here to cast `pthread_mutex_unlock`, which has the signature

```
int pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t*);
```

such that it can be used (for example, as a callback) with something that expects a function of the type

```
void function(void*);
```

Note that the wisdom of doing this depends strongly on the platform being targeted. It would be safer (i.e. more portable) to wrap the function with another, of the correct signature

```
void pthread_mutex_unlock_wrapper(void *mutex)
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock((pthread_mutex_t*)mutex);
}
```

this performs a cast to the argument type for `pthread_mutex_unlock` and discards the return type. This avoids the potential for stack corruption as a result of the caller and callee having a different understanding of the space requirements for arguments and return values (although in practice this may rarely be an issue for ignored return values, it is still better to be safe).

*Endnote:*

As a final note, since you tagged the question as C++, you could replace the `(pthread_mutex_t*)mutex` cast in the wrapper function with `static_cast<pthread_mutex_t*>(mutex)`, which performs an equivalent conversion, but can be more easily read and understood to be a cast. If you're genuinely using C++, you should prefer these "C++ style" casts everywhere, since they have clearly defined semantics (i.e. there are limits to what you can `static_cast`, what you can `dynamic_cast`, etc.) and they are easier to spot when reading code.

Answer (score 2):

It's a "C-style" cast to the type pointer-to-function taking a `void*` argument and not returning anything (with *undefined behaviour* due to the return type mismatch)....

Note that the type of `pthread_mutex_unlock` itself is:

```
int pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

It was probably used let some code that knew how to call a function expecting a `void*` actually make callbacks to `pthread_mutex_unlock`, which will work on most compilers because the `int` return value is typically just kept in a register for the caller so ignoring it doesn't affect the stack layout or unwinding, but some compilers might crash.

---

Example:

```
template <typename T>
class On_Destruction
{
  public:
    On_Destruction(void(*f)(T), T t)
      : f_(f), t_(t)
    { }

    ~On_Destruction() { f_(t_); }
  private:
    void (*f_)(void*);
    T t_;
};

...in some function...

    pthread_mutex_lock(my_mutex);
    On_Destruction<void*> guard((void(*)(void*))pthread_mutex_unlock,
                                (void*)&my_mutex);
    ...unlock when unwinding stack by return/break/throw etc...
```

There are much better ways to do this that don't have *undefined behaviour* (due to bodgy casts)... e.g. using [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Answer (score 1):

This line is not "self sufficient"

"As is" it tells you that the pointer to the function pthread_mutex_unlock() would be cast to a:

pointer to a function taking a pointer to anything as argument and returning nothing.